# Problem with service area gap with Network Analyst

Tags: arcgis-desktop, network-analyst, area

I am working on running Network Analyst to create a Service Area from a single location to all around it. Esri's network dataset was missing a couple crucial street lines, and so I uploading their street shapefile and added in three streets. Upon running the Service Area, I get a couple expected gaps, due to zero streets in that area (parks and forests etc). However, in the image below, I have a neighborhood where I have added in two streets that do not appear to be getting picked up, and thus creating a gap in this area.

These added lines have been calculated for Length_Mi, Speed Limit, and Minutes for time for travel (all the things required to create a network dataset)

I have checked that these lines are connected to endpoints (zoomed all the way in), but still no luck.

What else could I be missing?

[image]

Comment: After adding in the lines, did you rebuild the network?

Comment: Yup, and double checked it to make sure that wasn't the problem. I just ran over the street points, and although they are definitely connected (no way I could zoom in more than 1:0), they aren't registering as connected when I click on the Network Identify tool. This is crazy!

Comment: Well, it's not perfect, but I ended up editing an existing line to extend farther into that neighborhood, which gets rid of the service area gap seen above. When I independently create new lines, they seem to not take for some reason, despite rebuilding/checking for connectivity etc.

Comment: From the image I can't tell which lines you added. Did you use snapping? Do endpoints correspond with existing vertices in the original data since a network junction does not occur unless both features share a common vertex? The only other thing I can think to check without looking at the data is the attributes of those lines to see if they are consistent with all others and they're not entered as barriers or have a one-way restriction. That lower left intersection with no intermediate break values makes me suspicious.